# Zend_Form : Populate issue on a checkbox with value=0

Tags: zend-framework, checkbox, zend-form, populate, zend-filter

I don't understand why this checkbox with value=0 is checked by `populate()` whereas no data is passed about this checkbox...

My form element :

```
$this->addElement('multiCheckbox', 'etoiles', array(
    'filters'    => array('Int'),
    'separator' => '',
    'label_placement' => 'prepend',
    'label_class' => 'caseacocher',
    'decorators'  => $decorator_chain,
));

$listeEtoiles = array(
    '0' =>'Sans étoiles',
    '1' => '1 étoile"',
    '2' => '2 étoiles',
    '3' => '3 étoiles',
    '4' => '4 étoiles',
    '5' => '5 étoiles',
) ;
$this->getElement('etoiles')->addMultiOptions($listeEtoiles) ;
```

How I populate the form into my controller :

```
$this->view->searchForm->populate($this->getRequest()->getPost()) ;
```

What I get when dumping `$this->getRequest()->getPost('etoiles')` : `NULL`

What I get for my checkbox :

```
<input id="etoiles-0" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="0" name="etoiles[]">
```

I don't get it. How is it possible to get this checkbox checked, whereas there is NO data about `etoiles[]` ??
I just figured out that my "Int" filter has something to do with it. Should I remove it ? And what if I want to keep this Int filter ?

There are no validators. Should I add some ? What about the InArray validator ? My values array uses string indexes because I thought $_POST data were passed as strings. Is it a mistake ?

Any comment or help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

It may be a confusion between string `'0'` and int `0` (unchecked for radio form elements) and `null`, one quirk of PHP.

Especially as you are filtering input values to int, whereas your values array uses string indexes (is there a reason you do not use the default `InArray` validator ?)

Additionally I see that the `FormRadio` helper uses `in_array($opt_value, $value)` without the strict parameter to determine the checked property.

Comment: To be honest it's a copy/paste I made just to illustrate my problem. Forget about the validators, there are no validators. Should I add some ? What about this `InArray` validator ?
My values array uses string indexes because I thought `$_POST` data were passed as strings. Is it a mistake ?